# Zend framework can't make a new Translator object

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization, zend-framework2

I'm just getting started with Zend Framework. I decided to try it for my website translations.

I set the include path as follow:

```
set_include_path('.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/Zend/library');
```

And then straight from the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html) this doesn't work:

```
use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
$translator = new Translator();
```

Of course, I haven't loaded the `Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator` class anywhere, so I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator' not found in /path/file.php on line X

I see there are several things in the `Zend/Loader` directory, but I can't figure out how to use them and I don't even know if this is what I should be looking at. How do I load the `Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator` class?

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you using ZF1 or ZF2? The current tags on your question suggest ZF1, but the usage you describe suggests ZF2.

Comment: ZF2. I didn't see that there was a specific tag for it. I've just added it. Feel free to remove the other tag if it is not applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the auto loader, you can do:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
    'fallback_autoloader' => true,
));
$loader->register();

use Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator;
```